Retrieve/deploy metadata for PermissionSet works but changes don't reflect in Setup / Permission Sets
I need to make changes to unpackaged Permission Sets in several Salesforce orgs. My plan was to retrieve a specific Permission Set via the Salesforce CLI, modify it, then deploy it...
sf project retrieve start --metadata PermissionSet:MyPermissionSet
# Edit the XML then...
sf project deploy start --metadata PermissionSet: MyPermissionSet

Everything above seemed to work but when I went into the web user interface for the Salesforce org and went to Setup / Permission Sets and opened the one that corresponds to the API name of MyPermissionSet, none of the changes I made were reflected (field permissions allowing edit).
I re-downloaded the PermissionSet metadata to see if my changes were there... and they were.
Is there something else I need to do to get the Salesforce Org to use the updated metadata?

Assuming this isn't a bug, make sure you're logging into the correct org. It's an easy enough mistake to make when dealing with multiple orgs. Otherwise, this might be a time to contact Technical Support, because whatever you do in the API should definitely show up in the UI as well.

Ugh... that was it. Thank you so much. Had assumed a default that was not the case.

Let's just say I've had enough "uh oh" moments to become a bit paranoid about which org I'm connected to.
